# Command Line is too long when generating JAX-WS in Rational Application Developer

Tags: eclipse, jax-ws, ibm-rational, wsgen

I am using IBM's RAD which is basically eclipse in most respects.  We're on version 9.5.  We've generated web services with the wizard before, but not recently.  We think not since we upgraded to 9.5.  Now we have a need to add to our web services and we can't generate via the wizard because it gets the error

"The wsgen tool returned an error:
The command line is too long."

It does this seemingly no matter what combination of options we select in the wizard.  I've seen some thing about Maven's wsgen having this problem fixed in 2.3, but were not using Maven.  Though RAD ships with a wsgen that when I test it's version is 2.2.9.  They seem close enough that I am guessing those both refer to the version of wsgen, not of some Maven variant.

But that then leads to the question of whether and how to upgrade the wsgen in RAD.  Can I just download wsgen.exe and overlay it, or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 0):

What directory is your workspace in, and where did you install RAD? Did you use the default of "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP"?

This is really a limitation of windows, and not wsgen. I recommend installing RAD into a shorter directory such as C:\IBM\SDP, and using a workspace hung off either C:\workspaces, or a separate drive to shorted the file name. Also the command line could be affected the path of your Java project names (i.e. com.acme.widgets.subsystems.accounting.pojo.somelongname).

Also, if you are still under maintenance, you can upgrade/migrate to RAD 9.6 which is based on Eclipse 4.6, and as such has newer versions of ANT, Maven, and wsgen.